# change after purchase not giving the right breakdown

Tags: python

```
def main():
    money1 = input("Purchase price: ")
    money2 = input("Paid amount of money: ")
    price = int(money1)
    paid = int(money2)
    change = paid - price

    ten_euro = change // 10
    five_euro = change % 10 // 5
    two_euro = change % 5 // 2
    one_euro = (change % 2)

    if price < paid:
        print("Offer change:")
        if change >= 10:
            print(ten_euro, "ten-euro notes")
        if (change % 10) >= 5:
            print(five_euro, "five-euro notes")
        if (change % 5) >= 2:
            print(two_euro, "two-euro coins")
        if (change % 2) >= 2:
            print(one_euro, "one-euro coins")
    else:
        print("No change")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Create a program that asks how much purchases cost and the amount of paid money and then prints the amount of change. Simplify the program by only allowing the use of sums of 1, 2, 5, and 10 euros. Ensure that the total price is always in full euros.
My problem is with the one-euro coins, as it is not showing as expected.

Examples of how the program should work:

Purchase price: 12
Paid amount of money: 50
Offer change:
3 ten-euro notes
1 five-euro notes
1 two-euro coins
1 one-euro coins

Purchase price: 9
Paid amount of money: 20
Offer change:
1 ten-euro notes
1 one-euro coins

Answer (score 0):

This line is incorrect: `if (change % 2) >= 2`.

This can never be true. You probably meant: `if (change % 2) >= 1`.

Apart from that I think you could simplify the program by decrementing the `change` variable as you calculate the different denominations. You can use the builtin method `divmod` for this.

You can also check if the `ten_euro`, `five_euro`, etc are greater than zero in the printout rather than re-calculating their amount.

```
ten_euro, change = divmod(change, 10)
five_euro, change = divmod(change, 5)
two_euro, change = divmod(change, 2)
one_euro = change

if price < paid:
    print("Offer change:")
    if ten_euro:
        print(ten_euro, "ten-euro notes")
    if five_euro:
        print(five_euro, "five-euro notes")
    if two_euro:
        print(two_euro, "two-euro coins")
    if one_euro:
        print(one_euro, "one-euro coins")
else:
    print("No change")
```

Answer (score 0):

We got to calculate # one_euro count better and you are there.

Here is a working solution, included a check on the total change aswell.

```
def main():
    money1 = input("Purchase price: ")
    money2 = input("Paid amount of money: ")
    price = int(money1)
    paid = int(money2)
    change = paid - price

    ten_euro_count = change // 10
    five_euro_count = change % 10 // 5
    two_euro_count = change % 5 // 2

    sum_of_change = 0

    if price < paid:
        print("Offer change:")
        if change >= 10:
            print(ten_euro_count, "ten-euro notes")
            sum_of_change = sum_of_change + ten_euro_count * 10
        if (change % 10) >= 5:
            print(five_euro_count, "five-euro notes")
            sum_of_change = sum_of_change + five_euro_count * 5
        if (change % 5) >= 2:
            print(two_euro_count, "two-euro coins")
            sum_of_change = sum_of_change + two_euro_count * 2
        if change - sum_of_change != 0:
            one_euro_count = 1
            print(one_euro_count, "one-euro coins")
    else:
        print("No change")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Faulty decision structure;

```
if (change % 2) >= 2
```

Code change;

```
def main():
    money1 = int(input("Purchase price: "))
    money2 = int(input("Paid amount of money: "))
    change = money2 - money1

    ten_euro = change // 10
    five_euro = (change % 10) // 5
    two_euro = (change % 5) // 2
    total = 0

    if money1 < money2:
        print("Offer change:")
        if change >= 10:
            print(ten_euro, "ten-euro notes")
            total += ten_euro*10
        if (change % 10) >= 5:
            print(five_euro, "five-euro notes")
            total += five_euro*5
        if (change % 5) >= 2:
            print(two_euro, "two-euro coins")
            total += two_euro*2
        if change - total > 0:
            print(change-total, "one-euro coins")
    else:
        print("No change")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```